# Python Selenium Proxy TXT

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a Python script that goes to a site with a proxy, then refreshes, and goes to the other proxy in the proxys.txt file. ( this is for selenium, also a school project! )

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://example.com/")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please avoid tag spamming your question. Also please take the [tour] and read the FAQ on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be more specific, but if you want a way to use selenium with proxy, this is the way:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PROXY = "<IP>:<PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    driver.get("https://example.com/")
```